# Can Java Enumerations be merged (like Bitwise in C#)?

Tags: java, enums

Is there a way in Java to declare an enumeration whose values can be used together? For example:

```
enum FileAccess { Read, Write, ReadWrite }
```

Is it possible to define ReadWrite as `Read | Write` (or anything that would yield the same result)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You use [EnumSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```
EnumSet<FileAccess> readWrite = EnumSet.of(FileAccess.Read, FileAccess.Write);
```

This is actually somewhat more elegant than the C#/.NET way, IMO - aside from anything else, you can easily distinguish between a set and a single value.

Comment: Can you explain how you'd use this EnumSet to produce a read/write constant?

Comment: Exactly in the way I've shown - just make it a final variable. EnumSet is immutable.

Comment: But that gives you a Set, not an Enum, or indeed an integer that you could store in a database (like Enum.ordinal()).

Comment: If you want an external (DB) representation than bare enums are unacceptable -- using ordinals is a bad idea for maintainance reasons.  After adding a external representation to your enums, add a wrapper around EnumSet to manage the combined external representation in both directions.

Answer (score 4):

See [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) which allows you to do this efficiently:

```
EnumSet<FileAccess> set = EnumSet.of(READ, WRITE);
```